# declaring Hex char 'error: multi-character character constant' in c

Tags: c, hex, uart

In the function below, I'm reading two byte Hex characters from a UART. I'm trying to detect the start of the data which is the Hex character `FF`. The compiler is giving the error `error: multi-character character constant`. How should I be declaring `FF`?

```
void getData(void) {
    int i;
    static uint8_t detectedStartChar = 0;
    int buffans[264]; 
    int retchar;

    for (i = 0; i < 264; i++) {
        retchar = getch(UART_0);
        if (retchar == 'DD') {
            detectedStartChar = 1;
            buffans[i] = retchar;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quotes are for a single char. *0x* are for literals in hex notation.

Comment: Change `retchar == 'FF'` to `retchar == 0xff`

Comment: @MargaretBloom and @nsilent22, thanks, I'm also getting the error `error: variable 'buffans' set but not used` but it is used in the if loop?

Comment: You are setting this variable, but not using it later anywhere. So the compiler asks you what you are doing it for?

Comment: @nsilent22 but I'm using it in the `if loop`, I'm putting `retchar` in the array? Is that incorrect?

Comment: But what are you putting it for? They are stored in the array, function ends and array is destroyed. And the values from the array were used nowhere. So what is the point of storing them?

Comment: @nsilent22 thanks that makes sense - I print them out afterwards.

Comment: Adding code that prints them should make this warning disappear.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments the fix is  any of :-

```
if (retchar == 0xff ){ /* compare the value */

if (retchar == '\xff' ){ /* compare the character representation */
```